# How to write the data to the new column in existing csv File using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The below code is to read the data in `File1` from columns 2, 3, 4, 8 and write it in `NewFile`. The data in each column 2 (which is already stored in `temp_list`) should be searched in `File3`. If found, the data in third column of each row in `File3` is appended with the data stored in `temp_list`. But second `for` loop only considers the column2 data in first row. It is not considering the data in column 2 in remaining rows.

I gave print `var1` in second loop to see if each column 2 data (copied in `Newfile`) is being considered. But the output shows value only in the first row of `File3`. Values in other rows are not searched. Can someone please help me to understand the problem in my code?

```
import csv

f1 = csv.reader(open("C:/Users/File1.csv","rb"))
f2 = csv.writer(open("C:/Users/NewFile.csv","wb"))
f3 = csv.reader(open("C:/Users/File3.csv","rb"))

for row_f1 in f1:

    if not row_f1[0].startswith("-"):

        temp_list = [row_f1[1],row_f1[2],row_f1[3],row_f1[7]]

        var1 = row_f1[1]

        for row_f3 in f3:

            if var1 in row_f3:

                temp_list.append(row_f3[2])


        f2.writerow(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that when you do `for row_f3 in f3:` you read the file and it doesn't go to the beginning automatically. An option is to read it once saving the lines to a list, but checking if `var1` exists in a list every time will be very slow.

What is the field in row_f3 where you try to find var1? You can use a dictionary if the keys are the same:

```
d = dict()
for row_f3 in f3:
    d[row_f3[field_index]]  = row_f3[2]
```

And then:

```
   new_field = d.get(var1)
   if new_field is not None: temp_list.append(new_field)
```

How bigs are your files? If they are <1Gb you can also try pandas instead of reading line by line:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/File1.csv",header=None,index_col=None)
df1 = df1.loc[~df1[0].str.startswith("-"),[1,2,3,7]
df1[8] = df1[1].apply(lambda x: d.get(x))
df1.to_csv("C:/Users/NewFile.csv",header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description properly, the following should do what you want. The main problem with your code is that it doesn't close and reopen the third file in order to read and copy the data from it. Since your code is also sloppy about the closing of files in general, I've taken care of that by modifying it to use `with` statements which will handle it automatically.

```
import csv

with open("C:/Users/File1.csv", "rb") as file1, \
     open("C:/Users/NewFile.csv", "wb") as file2:
        f2 = csv.writer(file2)

        for row_f1 in csv.reader(file1):
            if not row_f1[0].startswith("-"):
                temp_list = [row_f1[1], row_f1[2], row_f1[3], row_f1[7]]
                var1 = row_f1[1]
                var1_found = False
                with open("C:/Users/File3.csv", "rb") as file3:
                    for row_f3 in csv.reader(file3):
                        if var1 in row_f3:
                            var1_found = True
                            break
                if var1_found:
                    with open("C:/Users/File3.csv", "rb") as file3:
                        for row_f3 in csv.reader(file3):
                            temp_list.append(row_f3[2])
                f2.writerow(temp_list)
```